# Pesquisa de duas tabelas MySQL em php

Tags: php, mysql, select

Eu tenho duas tabelas que são:

- Registo

  - Dorsal(id auto_increment primary key);
  - Nome;
  - Equipa;
- Classificacao

  - Lugar(id auto_increment primary key);
  - Dorsal (foreign key);

e o seguinte código em *PHP*:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT c.lugar, c.dorsal, r.nome, r.equipa from classificacao  c, registo r where c.dorsal = r.dorsal and r.categoria = '45'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['lugar'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['dorsal'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nome'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['equipa'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Isso funciona bem sem o lugar, apenas selecionando os dados da tabela registo mas assim não está a funcionar. Alguém sabe por quê?

Comment: A tabela onde tem o campo lugar chama-se "Lugar"?

Comment: @Hélder Não, peço desculpa já está emendado e obrigado

Comment: Podes colocar uma amostra dos dados das duas tabelas? E tens a certeza que existe um registo na tabela registo com categoria = 45?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Inner Join, Left Join ou Right Join** para relacionamentos em tabelas na sua consulta. Visualmente é mais bonito também.

```
SELECT 
    c.lugar, 
    c.dorsal, 
    r.nome, 
    r.equipa 
FROM 
    classificacao c
INNER JOIN
    registo r on r.dorsal = c.dorsal 
WHERE 
   r.categoria = 45
```

Verifique o nome da coluna, se está mesmo nessa tabela.
E coloque um `or die(mysqli_error())` no final da sua consulta, caso esteja dando algum erro.

Exemplo:

`mysqli_query($con, "Consulta SQL") or die(mysqli_error());`

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho muito a acrescentar na sua query, o Diego já melhorou ela.
Estou criando essa resposta só para mostrar o que é [HereDocs](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) e como interpolar variáveis nele.

```php
<?php

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT 
    c.lugar,
    c.dorsal,
    r.nome,
    r.equipa
FROM classificacao as c
INNER JOIN registo as r ON r.dorsal = c.dorsal
WHERE c.dorsal = r.dorsal AND r.categoria = 45
SQL;

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo <<<HTML
<tr>
    <td>{$row['lugar']}</td>
    <td>{$row['dorsal']}</td>
    <td>{$row['nome']}</td>
    <td>{$row['equipa']}</td>
</tr>
HTML;
}
```